# boto3: Lambda function is executed multiple time when writing file to S3

Tags: python, lambda, boto3

I am working on a utility that reads sqs messages and write to a s3 file. Using boto3 for the same. There are two parts to this:
A: python client: which invokes a Lambda function. Passing filename which will be used for s3 object name.
B: Lambda function which reads sqs messages and writes (100 records) to a file (in /tmp folder) and uploads it to s3 bucket. after message is read from sqs queue and written to file it is deleted from queue.
lambda function config: 256 Mb, 5 mins timeout. NO VPC.

when I invoke the lambda function from python client, the lambda function is executed multiple times. instead of 100 records, 200 records are deleted from sqs queue.
Getting below error in logs:

```
[DEBUG] 2017-08-01T10:24:59.613Z 99fdbfb1-76a3-11e7-9b81-c76e4a7f8294 Event needs-retry.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f78edd899a8>>

REPORT RequestId: 99fdbfb1-76a3-11e7-9b81-c76e4a7f8294 Duration: 29881.32 ms Billed Duration: 29900 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 46 MB 

[DEBUG] 2017-08-01T10:25:30.871Z ad06a4a7-76a3-11e7-b7d8-a7a246d0544c Event needs-retry.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f78edd28770>>

REPORT RequestId: ad06a4a7-76a3-11e7-b7d8-a7a246d0544c Duration: 29847.54 ms Billed Duration: 29900 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 52 MB
```

if I use the TEST button(from console) to invoke the lambda function it executes properly, only once (100 records are deleted from queue). but still get above error once.

can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?

## python client

```
nooflambdafunc = 1
for i in range(0, nooflambdafunc):
    num = str(i)
    print("file no:", i)
    js = json.dumps({'fkey':num})
    #s3response = lambdaclient.invoke(FunctionName=sqstos3lambdafuncname,Payload=js)
    print("SQS to S3 lambda function invoked for .", js)
```

## my lambda function

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
      
    config = Config(region_name='us-east-2', connect_timeout=300, read_timeout=500)
    #SQS connection
    sqsconnclient = boto3.client('sqs', config=config)
    sqsconnresource = boto3.resource('sqs', config=config)
    sourcesqsn = "target"
    #sqs queue url
    queueurl = sqsconnclient.get_queue_url(QueueName=sourcesqsn)
    sqsstring = queueurl.get('QueueUrl')    
     
    #boto3 S3 connection
    s3connresource = boto3.resource('s3', config=config)
    sourcebucket = "testcy"
    s3connclient = boto3.client('s3', config=config)    

    #get payload from lambda invoke function 
    js1 = json.dumps(event, indent=2)
    resp = json.loads(js1)
    filekey = resp["fkey"]
    print("key is:", filekey)

    #get # msgs from sqs queue as defined in numofrecords.
    filenamectr = filekey #take input from controller
    key = str(sourcesqsn + str(filenamectr) + ".json")
    numofrecords = 100 #number of records to write to file.

    #lambda file name.     
    filename = '/tmp/' + key
            
    # using client conn, write msgs (as per numofrecords)to single file
    for i in range(0, numofrecords):
        messages = sqsconnclient.receive_message(QueueUrl=sqsstring)        
        if messages.get('Messages'):
            m = messages.get('Messages')[0]
            mbody = m['Body']
            msg_body = mbody.replace('\n',' ')            
            mreceipt_handle = m['ReceiptHandle']            
            writer = open(filename, 'a') #open file in /tmp/            
            writer.write(msg_body + '\n') #write each msg on new line
            sqsconnclient.delete_message(QueueUrl=sqsstring, ReceiptHandle=mreceipt_handle)
        time.sleep(0.25) 
            
    writer.close()
    time.sleep(0.25)
    
    print("File size: ", os.path.getsize(filename) >> 20)

    # write the file to s3 bucket. 
    print("uploading file to s3 bucket...", filename)
    s3connresource.meta.client.upload_file(filename, sourcebucket, key)
    print("file uploaded to s3 bucket.")
```

Comment: Are 100 or 200 records being copied to the file? (you said 200 records are deleted)

Comment: 100 records are copied to file (as per numofrecords). but 200 are deleted from sqs queue.